# Unhandled rejection error: invalid input syntax for integer: "viewname"

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

I'm having an issue with this view it was working yesterday but now it wont even get to the next route after todo (eg "localhost:3000/todo/new") . my github link to my test app is 
https://github.com/Frosty21/node-Todo

This is the error that comes up

```
Unhandled rejection error: invalid input syntax for integer: "new"
    at Connection.parseE (/home/nfroese/lighthouse/Projects/other-test-projects/CRUD/server/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.
js:569:11)
    at Connection.parseMessage (/home/nfroese/lighthouse/Projects/other-test-projects/CRUD/server/node_modules/pg/lib/conne
ction.js:396:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/nfroese/lighthouse/Projects/other-test-projects/CRUD/server/node_modules/pg/lib/connection
.js:132:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:563:20)
```

**Update**

Figured the problem out video link to it below 
https://youtu.be/WYa47JkZH_U?t=1h15m2s

In Routes folder todo.js route GET '/:id' was conflicting with route GET '/new' as it  was above and therefore it was going to '/:id' so moving '/new' route above resolved the issue.

Wasnt sure how he was able to render the view for the duration.

Comment: Any trigger on the view?

Comment: Might want to add some more details on the what is happening where and what you are doing to cause the issue.

Comment: its triggering on the todo view as in this link  http://i.imgur.com/NAecHsM.png im wondering if its the postgres setup with the pg connection pulling errors that seems most likely.